# Python reading and writing to ttyUSB

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm using raspberry pi 3 and i can communicate to a port via terminal using the following commands:

to open port

> ssty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 -echo

> cat /dev/ttyUSB2&

To send messages i use:

> echo 'AT' > /dev/ttyUSB2

The response of the port is 'OK'

I doing a python code to save the answers of the terminal in a variable, i tried to use the pySerial library but doesn't work, is there any another method that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

Just use "serial" library. I use it and works good.

Comment: `import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate = 19200,
    timeout=0.5
    )

print("Connected to: " + ser.portstr)
count=1

while True:
        ser.write(something)
        line = ser.read(30)
        print(line)`

Comment: serial doesn't work in mi case, do you now another  another method?